# Match Characters in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am trying to match the first 5 characters of the Zip code in a LINQ query and I am using SubString to do this. First I am checking to see if either value is NULL so it doesn't bomb out of that. This is the code I am using but I get an error:

```
var lQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account")
    let AccountName = !a.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : a["name"]
    let Zip = !a.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : a["address1_postalcode"]
    let State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"]
    let Address = !a.Contains("address1_line1") ? string.Empty : a["address1_line1"]
    let City = !a.Contains("address1_city") ? string.Empty : a["address1_city"]
       where String.IsNullOrEmpty(Zip.ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(lLead.ZipCode) ? false : Zip.ToString().Substring(0,5).Equals(lLead.ZipCode.Substring(0,5))
       select new
       {
          Name = AccountName
       });
int c = lQuery.ToList().Count();
```

The error I get is:

"The method 'Where' cannot follow the method 'Select' or is not supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported methods."

Any ideas on how to get around this or suggestions on a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So some methods aren't supported in Linq to Entities, so you will need to get them into Memory and perform the actions there:

```
var lQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account")
    let AccountName = !a.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : a["name"]
    let Zip = !a.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : a["address1_postalcode"]
    let State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"]
    let Address = !a.Contains("address1_line1") ? string.Empty : a["address1_line1"]
    let City = !a.Contains("address1_city") ? string.Empty : a["address1_city"]
    select new 
    {
        AccountName, 
        Zip, 
        State, 
        Address, 
        City, 
        a.lLead
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Where(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Zip.ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.lLead.ZipCode) ? false : i.Zip.ToString().Substring(0,5).Equals(i.lLead.ZipCode.Substring(0,5))
    .Select(i => new
    {
        Name = i.AccountName
    });
```

The SQL Generated will look something like this overly simplified version:

```
    Select name... as AccountName, address1_city as City, etc
    From account
```

so if you notice there is not a where clause, thus returning all rows from table account.

---

Some filtering

```
var lQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account")
    let AccountName = !a.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : a["name"]
    let Zip = !a.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : a["address1_postalcode"]
    let State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"]
    let Address = !a.Contains("address1_line1") ? string.Empty : a["address1_line1"]
    let City = !a.Contains("address1_city") ? string.Empty : a["address1_city"]
    where Zip != null 
          && Zip != string.Empty 
          && lLead.ZipCode != null 
          && lLead.ZipCode != string.Empty 
          && Zip.Contains(lLead.ZipCode)
    select new 
    {
        AccountName, 
        Zip, 
        State, 
        Address, 
        City, 
        a.lLead
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Where(i => i.Zip.ToString().Substring(0,5).Equals(i.lLead.ZipCode.Substring(0,5))
    .Select(i => new
    {
        Name = i.AccountName
    });
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this won't do any filtering on the server and will bring in all data into memory.

Comment: Thanks! I have like over 10,000 accounts in the Account table. Is it possible to make it so it doesn't pull down the entire table?

Comment: Try my update, that should filter it down to a very small subset

Comment: Couldn't you use `SqlMethods.Like` to filter entirely on the server?

Comment: Thanks! I gave the second version a try and get "The method 'Where' cannot follow the method 'Select' or is not supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported methods." Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify some of the logic. This works on my end mocking up your result set as a `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>`, so I would guess it will work with your data without knowing what type is returned from gServiceContext.CreateQuery():

```
var lQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account")
                let AccountName = a.Contains("name") ? a["name"] : String.Empty
                let Zip = a.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? a["address1_postalcode"] : String.Empty
                where  Zip.Substring(0, 5).Equals(lLead.ZipCode.Substring(0, 5))
                select new
                            {
                                Name = AccountName
                            });
```

You can also call .Count() on lQuery directly. This lets the LINQ implementation pick the most efficient way to count the results, rather than loading the entire result set into memory and using LINQ to Objects to access the .Count property of the list you return from .ToList().

```
int c = lQuery.Count();
```

Comment: What happens if a Zip is NULL, won't it bomb on the Substring?